# Knex NodeJS insert date timezone compatible inside PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timezone, knex.js

I have a postgreSQL table like this:

```
table.string('id');
table.string('name');
table.specificType('data', 'JSONB');
table.timestamp('runDate');
table.boolean('done').default(false);
```

I wonder what is the safe way to insert date time inside the database.

This is what I do:

```
await _i_.knex("jobs")
    .transacting(ctx ? ctx.transaction : null)
    .insert({
        id: job.id,
        name: job.name,
        data: job.data,
        id: job.id,
        runDate: job.runDate,
        done: false
        });
```

When I want to query my table, I use:

```
  return await _i_.knex('jobs')
        .transacting(ctx ? ctx.transaction : null)
        .whereRaw('"runDate" < NOW()')
        .andWhere('done', false)
        .returning("*")
        .update({
            done: true
        });
```

So I can have issue with the timezone if my nodeJS server doesn't have the save timezone than my PostgreSQL.

How do you manage that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `knex` [creates](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-timestamp) `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`) type for `.timestamp()` columns for PostgreSQL. So, your date and time are stored with timezone. For inserting timestamp values I like to use `moment` [package](https://momentjs.com/).

```
const moment = require('moment');
const dateStr = moment().utc().format();
console.log(dateStr); // => Date in format 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'
knex.insert({ runDate: dateStr })
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the DB time on insert: ...`runDate: knex.raw("NOW()")`...

Then the storage and retrieval dates will be synchronized to the same timezone.

BUT if the `job.runDate` needs millisecond accuracy, or the record has been held for a significant amount of time before storage, then this would not be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you The runDate is a different date than now 